# How to change the hashcode?

Tags: c#, hashset, gethashcode

I have a class that creates objects:

```
public class Creator
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        //I need to change the field of the Dog class here  
    }

    public Dog Create()
    {
        return new Dog("Buddy", new DateTime(2000, 9, 29));
    }
}
```

And class Dog:

```
    public class Dog
    {
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; private set; }

        public Dog(string name, DateTime birthDate)
        {
            Name = name;
            BirthDate = birthdate;
        }

        protected bool Equals(Dog other)
        {
            return Name.Equals(other.Name) 
                    && BirthDate.Equals(other.BirthDate);
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
            if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
            if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
            return Equals((Dog) obj);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return unchecked(Name.GetHashCode()*397 
                             ^ BirthDate.GetHashCode());
        }

        public void ChangeName(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in another class I add created Dog objects in hashset. 
I need to make the hashset stop working correctly, by changing the object of the Dog class from the Creator class. How can I do this?

Comment: `I need to make the hashset stop working correctly` - Really? You need it to stop working correctly? By allowing the name to be changed when that value is used to calculate the hashcode, you are achieving exactly that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your object isn't immutable, and you are using it as the "key" of an `HashSet<>`... This is looking for trouble...

```
Dog dog = Create();
HashSet<Dog> dogs = new HashSet<Dog>();

dogs.Add(dog);
Console.WriteLine(dogs.Contains(dog)); // True

dog.ChangeName("Foo");
Console.WriteLine(dogs.Contains(dog)); // False
```

If you change one of the properties the `GetHashCode()` is calculated from **after** inserting the object in the `HashSet<>` you'll "break" the `HashSet<>`.

Comment: But I'm creating a hashset in another class. How can I change the Dog fields from the Creator class? I need to do this in "DoSomething" method

Comment: @Maxter You can't. The "correct" way would be to remove the item from the `HashSet<>`, modify it, readd it to the `HashSet<>`. The `HashSet<>` "caches" the `GetHashCode()` of its items. The "right" way to do it is to not base the `GetHashCode()` on mutable fields. For example you could base it only on `BirthDate` (it can't be modified once created in your code)

Comment: Thank you, now I understand the work of `GetHashCode` better. But my task is to make the hashset work incorrectly, and I can only change the structure of the Creator class.

Comment: @Maxter If you modify the `dog` inside the `DoSomething()` then the `HashSet<>` will work *"incorrectly"* (it will work *correctly* by its specification, *incorrectly* by a layman point of view)